# Avoiding producing a cycle between classes

Tags: java

I'm still learning about OOP and I have run into a issue.

Say I have a GUI class, the GUI has a action button that when clicked calls another classes object to produce some logic. How would I go about then making a change in the GUI without producing a object of the GUI class? I would be producing a cycle like this.

```
public class MainGUI {
  Vehicle car = new Vehicle();

  public void Button(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    car.addCar(x);
  }

  public void setIcon(){
    label1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/some 
    image")));
  }
}

public class Vehicle {
  MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();

  public void addCar(int x){
    if(x == 5){
      gui.setIcon();
    }
  }
}
```

Am I also right in thinking that its a bad idea to have logic in a GUI class?

Thanks

Comment: People are down-voting you because your question does not contain an example of code that you have attempted and lacks context.

Comment: Oh alright I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();
```

in your Vehicle class does not reference your main gui. It's a whole new gui that you've created inside that class

Instead you should pass a reference that your vehicle can interact with; the simplest way would be via the `addCar` method itself:

```
public class MainGUI {
  Vehicle car = new Vehicle();

  public void Button(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    car.addCar(x, this);
  }

  public void setIcon(){
    label1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/some 
    image")));
  }
}

public class Vehicle {
  public void addCar(int x, MainGui gui){
    if(x == 5){
      gui.setIcon();
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could pass the MainGui reference to Vehicle's constructor and store the reference as a class variable. The point is that you need the reference to your one gui object not making arbitrary new objects.

Comment: Okay great, yeah this is what I was looking for, thanks! Can I ask something else? Would you have the executed main in the GUI since its a higher class or in another class? Currently, I have it in another class but am unsure what the best flow is. First time working with GUIs so unsure about them a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I would have put the main method in its own class. It can spin up the GUI thread and from there, along with any utilities necessary.

Comment: Basically it's a question of "who has what". You have an app, which has a gui. Your app also has vehicles. Those vehicles are displayed in the gui. So App should be a class, which should have instances of Gui and Vehicle which it can control. The App can pass the vehicle to display in the gui as needed. and so on.

Comment: Okay, yeah thats what I have been doing so far. Just wanted to check its the best method of doing it. Thanks so much for the help!